# Is it possible to clear a given cache for all instances registered with Spring Boot Admin?

Tags: spring-boot-admin

I'm currently leveraging the features in Spring Boot Admin that allow changing log levels and clearing caches.  Best as I can tell, one is able to change the log levels for all instances at once, but the caches seem to only affect a single instance.

Is there a configuration option that allows for clearing the cache for all instances with a single click?  If not is this something that could added via custom view?
We are not currently leveraging a centralized cache solution such as Redis so I think being able to clear the cache for an individual instance and all instances would be very helpful.
Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of Spring Boot Admin version `2.7.5` this appears to be working.

The "Instance" button on the page now toggles to "Application" if clicked upon.  This allows using clearing the cache across all instances.

At the time of my original question I was on `2.7.1`.  Not sure if there was a bug or if this feature wasn't implemented yet in this version.